# Looking for a quick "randomish" way to map 1..N to 1..N and back

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

This is related to a programming problem I have, but posted here because I think I'll get a better answer.

I've got database records that have ID's 1,2,3,....  Assume I'll never have more than a couple million records.  Currently you can view that data by http://mysite/000000001, http://mysite/000000002, etc.  Manager would rather those numbers look more random so people don't think "oh I'm the 352nd person to sign up".  Are there any quick ways to generate a 1-1 reversible mapping that looks *basically* random?

Ideas:

- Deterministically scrambling the digits and adding some constant is easily reversible but not quite random-looking enough.
- I know I can multiply by a prime factor of N (say I choose N to be a billion, I can multiply by 384720347) and then mod by N, which will give a 1-1 mapping.  That's probably the lower bound on "random-looking", but doesn't seem easily reversible.  (Correct me if I'm wrong).

Notes:

- Of course I don't want to create a million-item lookup table.
- "N" isn't restricted to anything in particular, other than being somewhere between (say) a billion and a trillion.  If an algorithm only works assuming N is prime, or N is a power of 2, or N is 932483920 then that's acceptable.

Comment: Just use any 10 letters instead of the ten digits - nobody would guess the correspondence.

Comment: Or create a one-to-many map from 10 digits to 10 digits + 26 letters (choose it to be injective for reverse look-up and surjective for more "random looking" and balance it so that each digits gets mapped to 3-4 elements which are a digit and 2-3 letters) and randomly pick an element out of 3-4 possibilities. Assigned alfa-numeric IDs will be random.

Comment: "but doesn't seem easily reversible" It is fairly easy to invert it. One must solve a linear congurence equation $ax \equiv b\pmod n$ which can be done for example using [Euclids algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) and for almost all typical programming languages there already exists libraries for this.

Comment: What you want cannot be done, since very many of the N numbers, regardless of what they actually represent, have a non-random-looking structure; i.e., one of the secret codes will have to be $000001$, etc.

Comment: You could make "random-looking" more precise. If you just want consecutive numbers to look different, here's one (for 6-digit numbers): abcdef->(a+f)(b+e)cdef, where the addition is modulo 10. If you want to avoid zeros, just add a couple of non-zero digits in suitable positions.

Comment: This is called obfuscation, I'm sure it has been asked many times before in more programming-oriented forums.  Have you checked some of the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554286/obfuscating-an-id ?

Comment: @Kibble I had meant to delete it earlier per the earlier the comment/answer from Erick Wong that stated it should not have been on this site in the first place, and the reference provided me enough to go forward.  But I'd forgotten and only remembered when I was alerted to the new answer.  How do you recommend I better resolve this situation?

Comment: This question is on-topic here and Erick Wong's comment does not say that this question does not belong here. The question if this belongs here is a decision that should be made by the *community* (when the question has answers) and not by you. As you *should* know, deleting the question also deletes the answer, and the effort and time spent by the answerer will be wasted. That is not an accepted practice. This site is not only for the benefit of the person asking the question, but also serves as a resource for anyone who may have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several good options listed in the [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554286/obfuscating-an-id) Erick Wong gave in the comments. Below I will flesh out a simple algorithm (based on OPs own suggestion) for generating a random looking id and how we easily can invert it.

---

Choose a large number $N$, any number $k$ that is co-prime to $N$ and compute the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of $k$, i.e. solve
$$kx \equiv 1 \pmod{N}$$

This can be done using the [extended Euclidian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Computation) as mentioned in the comments or if $N$ is not really really large you can simply brute-force evaluate $kx\pmod{N}$ for $x=1,2,3,\ldots$ untill you find the correct solution. This is a one-time computation so it's not critical how this is done.

This is all the setup we need. You can now transform to a random looking id using

$$\text{id}_{\rm random} = \text{id}\cdot k \pmod{N}$$

and by multiplying the equation above by $x$ and reducing mod $N$ it follows that you can recover the original id from the random looking id as 
$$\text{id}  = \text{id}_{\rm random}\cdot x \pmod{N}$$

The mapping above is one-to-one since if we have two id's id$_1$ and id$_2$ that maps to the same random-looking id then

$$(\text{id}_1-\text{id}_2)k \equiv 0 \pmod{N}$$

Now since $k$ and $N$ are coprime and as long as id$_1$,id$_2 < N$ we must have $\text{id}_1 = \text{id}_2$. Note that this requires $N$ to be larger than the maximum number of id's you will ever need.

One should also compute the first few random id's to check that they indeed look random (for example for the case $N=1000$ and $k=101$ then we get a very systematic looking sequence in the beginning where $1,2,3,4,5,\ldots$ transforms into $101,202,303,404,505,\ldots$).